# What is the meaning of $\tau$=$Gb/l$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, material-science, metals

What is the physical meaning or intuition of the Shear Stress vs  Shear Modulus and Burger Vector over length relation($\tau$=$Gb/l$). I have seen this formula being used to determine length in case of the Orowan Mechanism when the length is shortened. However I do not understand at times what role would the factor $b$ play? I do not think that I can have Burger's vector in case of Orowan Mechanism do I? Please compare the $b$ and $l$ factor in the formula that I have just stated.

Comment: This link is useful for you? https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/frank-read-source

Comment: @Sebastiano The full text is not visible to me.

Comment: Apparently, it's a reference to several books. I'm sorry I didn't help you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Its alright. Atleast you responded.

Comment: I can reply, especially on TeX.SE. The other users will also answer. Greetings.